# How to pass function parameters if using one or more parameters

Tags: pandas, func, args

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
#Create df.
import pandas as pd 


d = {'dep_var' : pd.Series([10, 20, 30, 40], index =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), 
      'one' : pd.Series([9, 23, 37, 41], index =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
       'two' : pd.Series([1, 6, 5, 4], index =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d) 

print(df)

   dep_var  one  two
a       10    9    1
b       20   23    6
c       30   37    5
d       40   41    4


#Define function.

def df_two(dep_var, ind_var_1, ind_var_2):

    global two

    data = {
        dep_var: df[dep_var],
        ind_var_1: df[ind_var_1],
        ind_var_2: df[ind_var_2]
    
    }


    two = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return two

# Execute function.

df_two("dep_var", "one", "two")


dep_var one two
a   10  9   1
b   20  23  6
c   30  37  5
d   40  41  4
```

Works perfect.  I'd like to, fairly new at this, be able to use a single function when using say three or four parameters, of course, using the above code I get error message with third parameter.

So rookie move I define another function with 3 parameters.

```
def df_three(dep_var, ind_var_1, ind_var_2, ind_var_3):

    global three

    data = {
        dep_var: df[dep_var],
        ind_var_1: df[ind_var_1],
        ind_var_2: df[ind_var_2],
        ind_var_3: df[ind_var_2]
    
    }


    three = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return three
```

I've tried *args, *kargs, mapping and host of things with no luck.  My sense is I'm close but need a way to tell the function that sometimes there might be one, two, or three parameters, and then map one, two or three parameters to created dataframe.

Comment: how are you calling `df_three`?

Answer (score 1):

Use unpack `*args`:

```
def foo(dep_var, *args):
    global df

    data = {dep_var: df[dep_var]}
    for a in args:
        data[a] = df[a]
    
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And then you can call

```
foo('dep_var', 'one')

foo('dep_var', 'one', 'two')
```

To eliminate the need of `global` argument, I'd pass `df` to the function as well:

```
def foo(df, dep_var, *args):
    data = {dep_var: df[dep_var]}
    for a in args:
        data[a] = df[a]
    
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

More information on [*args](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to select only some columns from a data frame, in a certain order. You can just pass a list of the column names for that:

```
two[["dep_var", "one", "two"]]
```

If you want to, you can pack that into a function, using tuple unpacking to have a variable number of arguments.

```
def select(df, *columns):
    return df[list(columns)]
```

This should directly work with your use cases:

```
select(two, "dep_var", "one", "two")
select(three, "dep_var", "one", "two", "three")
```

Note that I also passed the data frame variable, so you don't need to rely on a global variable.

The call to `list` is needed, because tuple unpacking produces, well, a tuple. And using a tuple as an index to the data frame produces different results than using a list.

You might want to append a `.copy()` to the return line, depending on how you use the return value of this.

A variable number of arguments also includes zero, so you might want to add a check for that.